# JavaScript getElementById().value returning a value but giving "Undefined" when assigned to variable

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to get a form to submit via AJAX request.

There are many forms on the pages and each form has a different id tag for the relevant input field:

My JavaScript needs to be able to differentiate between each form and I am doing this by the id tag.

When I run in chrome's console I get my expected value:

```
document.getElementById("form-quantity-1").value;
"1"
```

When I assign to a variable:

```
var quan = document.getElementById("form-quantity-1").value;
undefined
```

I am at a loss as to why.

Comment: Can you provide your form id and input text field id

Answer (score 3):

The expression

```
var x = 1
```

doesn't return a value.  The console returns the value of the expression you just typed, and since `var x = 1` doesn't have a value, the console prints `undefined`.  However, the variable is still set, which you can see if you just enter the name of the variable:

```
>> x
1
```

Comment: beat me to it. i do wanna add that assignment without declaration *does* return the assigned value. e.g.: `let a; a = 5;` the first declaration statement returns `undefined` but the second statement returns `5`.